# Unity/C# - Connect to Unity Server on another computer

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm currently writing the Networking backend for a game I'm creating in Unity. The problem I'm facing is connecting to my server on another computer (on the same local network). I'm extremely new to uNet and what it entails, so the help is very appreciated.

I've followed a few tutorials, but none have fixed the problem that I've been facing. There's currently no connection at all coming through to the server. I've initialised the server, created sockets, used Network.Listen() to listen to packets coming through the port - but nothing quite yet.

This is a test project that I'm doing before implementing into the game, so sorry for the not-so-clean code.

**The IP's are specified in Inspector, but used "127.0.0.1" to preset it. Sorry for the confusion!**

Here's the client-side code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class ClientConnector : NetworkManager
{
NetworkClient m_client;

public GameObject screenCanvas;
bool socketConnection = false;
bool serverConnection = false;
bool connectingToSocket = false;
bool connectingToServer = false;
bool connectedToServer = false;

public int socketConnectionPort = 8888;
public int serverConnectionPort = 8899;
public string connectionIP = "127.0.0.1";
public int maxConnectionsNumber = 10;

int reliableChannelID;
int socketID;
int socketConnectionID;
int serverConnectionID;

void Start ()
{
    NetworkTransport.Init();
    m_client = new NetworkClient();

    if (SetupConnection())
    {
        ConnectSocket();
    }

    if (socketConnection)
    {
        ConnectServer();
    }
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    NetworkTransport.Shutdown();
}

public void ConnectSocket()
{
    connectingToSocket = true;
    byte error;
    socketConnectionID = NetworkTransport.Connect(socketID, connectionIP, socketConnectionPort, 0, out error);

    if (socketConnectionID != 0)
    {
        socketConnection = true;
        connectingToSocket = false;
    }
}

public void ConnectServer()
{
    connectingToServer = true;
    byte error;
    serverConnectionID = NetworkTransport.Connect(socketID, connectionIP, serverConnectionPort, 0, out error);

    if (!ReferenceEquals(socketID, 0))
    {
        serverConnection = true;
        connectedToServer = true;
        connectingToServer = false;

        SendSocketMessage();
    }
}

bool SetupConnection()
{
    ConnectionConfig config = new ConnectionConfig();

    reliableChannelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);

    HostTopology topology = new HostTopology(config, maxConnectionsNumber);
    socketID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topology, socketConnectionPort);
    if (!ReferenceEquals(client, null))
    {
        client.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
    }

    if (ReferenceEquals(socketID, 0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Socket open. Socket ID is: " + socketConnectionID);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

void Update ()
{
    ReceiveAndHandlePacket();
}

void ReceiveAndHandlePacket()
{
    int recChannelID;
    byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int dataSize;
    byte error;

    NetworkEventType networkEvent = NetworkTransport.Receive(out socketID, out socketConnectionID, out recChannelID, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

    switch (networkEvent)
    {
        case NetworkEventType.Nothing:
            {
                Debug.Log("No packets!");
                break;
            }

        case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
            {
                break;
            }

        case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
            {
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(recBuffer);
                bufferSize = (int)stream.Position;
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                string data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as string;
                Debug.Log("Received Packet from Server saying: " + data);
                break;
            }

        case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
            {
                Debug.Log("Disconnected.");
                break;
            }                
    }
}

void SendSocketMessage()
{
    byte error;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, "Connecting from Client.");

    int bufferSize = (int)stream.Position;

    NetworkTransport.Send(socketID, socketConnectionID, reliableChannelID, buffer, bufferSize, out error);
}    

void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Connected to Socket on " + connectionIP);
}
}
```

and here is the server-side code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class ServerControl : NetworkManager
{
public GameObject connectionsScreen;
public int maxConnectables;
public int socketConnectionPort = 8888;
public string socketConnectionIP = "127.0.0.1";
public int serverConnectionPort = 8899;

bool useNat;
List<NetworkClient> connections = new List<NetworkClient>();

bool serverInitialized;
int channelID;
int socketID;
int connectionID;

void Start()
{
    useNat = !Network.HavePublicAddress();
    NetworkTransport.Init();

    if (SetupSocket())
    {
        InitializePeerServer();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    ReceiveAndHandlePackets();
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    NetworkTransport.Shutdown();
}

public bool SetupSocket()
{
    ConnectionConfig config = new ConnectionConfig();
    channelID = config.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);

    HostTopology topology = new HostTopology(config, maxConnections);
    socketID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topology);

    byte error;
    connectionID = NetworkTransport.Connect(socketID, socketConnectionIP, socketConnectionPort, 0, out error);

    if (connectionID != 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Socket open on: " + socketConnectionPort + " with IP: " + socketConnectionIP);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public void InitializePeerServer()
{
    NetworkConnectionError serverStatus;
    serverStatus = Network.InitializeServer(maxConnectables, serverConnectionPort, useNat);
    Network.Listen(serverConnectionPort);

    switch (serverStatus)
    {
        case NetworkConnectionError.NoError:
            {
                serverInitialized = true;
                break;
            }

        default:
            {
                serverInitialized = false;
                break;
            }
    }
}

public void ReceiveAndHandlePackets()
{
    int recChannelID;
    byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int dataSize;
    byte error;
    NetworkEventType networkEvent = NetworkTransport.Receive(out socketID, out connectionID, out recChannelID, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

    switch (networkEvent)
    {
        case NetworkEventType.Nothing:
            connectionsScreen.transform.GetChild(6).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Message: \nNo packets!";
            break;

        case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
            {
                Debug.Log("Incoming connection.");
                break;
            }

        case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
            {
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(recBuffer);
                bufferSize = (int)stream.Position;
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                string data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as string;
                Debug.Log("Received packet, saying: " + data);
                connectionsScreen.transform.GetChild(6).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Message Received: " + data;
                break;
            }

        case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent:
            {
                Debug.Log("Disconnected.");
                break;
            }
    }
}

public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    base.OnClientConnect(conn);

    NetworkClient client = new NetworkClient(conn);
    connections.Add(client);
    Debug.Log("New connection from " + conn.address);
}
}
```

Any and all help is very greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: you need to change the server part to be the IP of the machine its going to run on, same with the client, otherwise if the server only end is still only listening to 127.0.0.1 its only listening for itself.

Comment: The IP is specified in the Inspector, preset to be 127.0.0.1. Though, by some chance it's ignoring the Inspector's field, I'll try that out as well nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Field values in the inspector override the default value due to the way serialization works; that's not the problem.